# Python progressbar does not display

Tags: python

I've got this function that takes some time to complete and I'd like to display the current progress per element in the list.

This is how it's coded:

```
import progressbar

def func(self):
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(
        maxval=len(some_list),
        widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()]
    )
    progress = 0
    bar.start()
    for r in some_list:
        #heavy calculation
        progress += 1
        bar.update(progress)
    bar.finish()
```

Yet when I run, the progressbar isn't displayed (nothing in fact is), the function just does its thing and when the function ends 20 seconds later I suddenly get the full bar in the console

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Kubuntu latest version with python 3.7.4 and PyCharm.

Comment: Are you executing it from PyCharm?

Comment: @Marcos yes I am

Comment: try flushing stdout. If that fixes it, it's an output buffering issue. You'll have to use the python2 approach from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function. For example, try flushing after every bar update

Comment: It would be good if you link what `progressbar` module you are using. There are more than one implementation floating around.

Answer (score 3):

Consider running it not from an IDE, sometimes they get a messy std output. Just run it with plain `python` like this:

```py
python3 your_script.py
```

Comment: Indeed, seems like the issue is purely PyCharm since it works perfectly in the console